# Attacking WPA/WPA2 ; Clarification on deauthentication packets

Tags: wpa2, wep, wpa-enterprise

In the attack on WPA/WPA2, one way to force a handshake is by sending deauth packets to force the client to deauntheticate. During reauthentication attempts, the handshake can the be captured. Here is my question: Why is it that multiple reauthentication packets are used? Why isnt one deauthentication packet not enough?

I see on most tutorials the command uses several packets. why not one packet?

Answer (score 1):

Only one four way authentication exchange is required. You can either wait for it or send a single deauth pack to a connected client so that it would re initiate the connection. The reason why they use multiple deauth could be the low SNR of the network. In order to successfully deauthenticate they might need multiple packets as some might get dropped.

Comment: But regular data packets in the network do not typically get dropped at such a rate to warrant multiple transmissions. How different are these deauth packets?