# How many packets required to deauth WPA?

Tags: wpa2, aircrack-ng, wep

When using aircrak-ng to attack WPA; Why do I need to send many de-authenticate packets to force the host to deauthenticate? Why is one packet not enough to cause deauthentication?

Comment: you asked almost the same question yesterday and got an answer. Instead of asking again it might be better to explain to the community what was not satisfying with the answer you got: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139358/attacking-wpa-wpa2-clarification-on-deauthentication-packets